# Error when integrating Adapty sdk React Native Expo for in app purchase

Tags: android, react-native, expo, in-app-purchase

[Error: #0 (unknown): Failed to deserialize a native error message]
http://192.168.1.22:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=PACKAGE.NAME&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:229219

I am getting this error when I am adding

`useEffect(() => { adapty.activate('PUBLIC_SDK_KEY'); }, []);`

How can I solve this? Thank you!

I am using a development build.