# Adapty React Native: "Failed to deserialize a native error message" on SDK initialization

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

(while the question is similar to [Error when integrating Adapty sdk React Native Expo for in app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650279/error-when-integrating-adapty-sdk-react-native-expo-for-in-app-purchase) I have more details that might help on resolution)

I'm trying to initialize the SDK:

```
   adapty.activate(env.adaptySdkKey, { customerUserId }).then(async () => {
          ...
   });
```

My `env.adaptySdkKey` and `customerUserId` are set and valid. However when I'm initing I get a console warning:

`Failed to deserialize a native error message`

Digging down further into React Native bridge and putting a breakpoint there reveals the following details with the provided error data object:

```
{
  "code":"adapty_native_error",
  "message":"Argument 'id' was not passed to a native module.",
  "domain":"RCTErrorDomain",
  [...]
}
```

I'm on Adapty React Native SDK 2.4.2.

What am I doing wrong? (Tried iOS-only. I currently can't test Android so I don't know it happens on Android too or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of this library :) By all means, you can open issues, when you experience something like this and I'll try to help.

From the provided code I can see only one possible buggy place: `customerUserId` should be a nullable string (`string | undefined | null`) and native layer may throw an error if you've passed a number for example.

Although in this `customerUserId` case the error should be: "*Argument 'user_id' was not passed to a native module.*"
The only place, where I can expect `'id'` is in `adapty.getPaywall(paywallId)` method.

Make sure, that:

1. `getPaywall` is not being called somewhere without a first required argument
2. The first `paywallId` argument is of string type

I might not receive updates here, so feel free to open an issue if a problem remains. Meanwhile, I'll make sure that errors deserialize without any pain

Comment: After further investigation I've found that I was passing an object whereas I should be passing ID string. I had some refactoring around Adapty and paywalls but forgot to change that one line of code (which was previously working with object instead of ID).